# How to draw or plot illustrative figures?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, matlab, 3d

stackexchange users
I would like to plot or draw some illustrative figures for my research paper. I've tried GeoGebra already. But couldn't draw them as I wanted.
So my question is How can I draw them?
Or would you tell me what are their functions so that I can plot them in Matlab?
I post the figures in here, so that you can understand what am I looking for. 
Thanks for your reply.
*P.S. If I am in a wrong forum please help me to find the appropriate forum for asking this question.*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe TikZ worth trying?

Comment: @MaMing, your suggestion is good, but TikZ requires TeX.

Comment: You can draw functions on GeoGebra as well though ..

Comment: I tried GeoGebra, but I couldn't draw them accurately. because in the 1st and last figures I cannot draw some pieces of the curve. Also in the middle figure (3D), I don't have the coordination of points. Also, I want to place a bilateral in the cube so its a little bit different to what it is in here. @Sawarnik

Answer (score 2):

I like the program [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/). See a [tutorial](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) and a [gallery of examples](http://asy.marris.fr/asymptote/). Also, you can see the drawing in [Calculating line integrals via Stokes theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016138/calculating-line-integrals-via-stokes-theorem).

Comment: I have problem for installing `Asymptote` on Mac OSX. Also, it seems that Asymptote needs the function of figures as well But, I don't access to mathematical functions(I would plot them by matlab if I had the functions). Is there any easier way? @martín-blas-pérez-pinilla

Comment: @Electricman, you need 3D figures or 2D is enough? All the figures that you want draw are graphics of functions? See also GNUplot.

Comment: It seems that the first and last figures are 2D and the middle one is 3D. The middle one (3D plot) looks like a function but I think the others(2D plots) are only illustrative figures. They look very nice (vector image format) in the original paper but I should modify them and write my own notation on it. I will check GNUplot, Thanks for helping @martín-blas-pérez-pinilla

Comment: @Electricman: Re: installing Asymptote on OS X. [See here](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/binaries.html). You'll need need the [Homebrew command line package manager](http://brew.sh). As far as Matlab goes, I've given up trying to make publication quality figures within Matlab. I just get the basic content/data in and then export to EPS or PDF. Then I use a vector graphics program to actually make things look nice and get the typography right. I use Adobe Illustrator, but [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) might be a good free alternative. I also use [EazyDraw](http://eazydraw.com) on OS X.